# TikZ tree beside table

Tags: tables, minipage, tikz-trees, apa6

I would like to place a TikZ tree beside a table. The document type is apa. So the tree has four branches and therefore I want to place a 4 x 6 table to the left of the tree. The height of the branches shall match the heigth of the rows.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[doc,apacite]{apa}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%Tikz%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%Table%%%%%
\usepackage{ctable} % needed for \cmidrule{}
\usepackage{multirow} % needed for \multirow{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}  

\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}

    % Overall layout of the tree
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=2.0cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.0cm, sibling distance=3.0cm]
    \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=3.0cm, sibling distance=3.0cm]

    % Styles for bags and leafs
    \tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
    \node{}
        child {
            node{U2}        
                child {
                    node[label=right:
                        ]{D2} {}
                            child {node[end, label=right:
                            {R1}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$1-R$}
                            node[below]  {}}
                            child {node[end, label=right:
                            {R2}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {$1-D$}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {D1}] {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {$D$}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
                edge from parent 
                node[above] {}
                node[below]  {$1-u$}
        }
        child {
            node{U1}        
                child{
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {$T$}] {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
            edge from parent         
                node[above] {$u$}
                node[below]  {}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{minipage}

    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}

    %\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
     &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
    %\end{table}

    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help my. I have spent hours with it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I corrected it!

Comment: You must avoid blank lines because they are interpreted as `\parskip`

Comment: Where? Inside the minipage section?

Comment: Each minipage environment is interpreted as a **box** (as a **letter**). A blank line between both minipages inserts a `parskip`. If what you want is to align on top both *minipages* you must add `\vspace{0pt}` after of `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` in both and remove the blank line between them.

Comment: @skpblack: Thank you. \vspace{0pt} works!

Comment: Now that your questions have received good answers, don't forget that you can accept the ones that you consider solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like that:

[image]

Then you can name the parent node of the tree and position a matrix beside the tree using the `matrix` and the `fit` library.

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%Tikz%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  trees,
  matrix,
  fit
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
  \newcommand\sibdist{2cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      grow=right, sloped,
      bag/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
      end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny},
      sibling distance=\sibdist,
      level 1/.style={level distance=2.0cm},
      level 2/.style={level distance=3.0cm},
      every node/.style={font=\strut},
      ]
    \node(n){}% named parent node
        child {
            node{U2}        
                child {
                    node[label=right:
                        ]{D2} {}
                            child {node[end, label=right:
                            {R1}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$1-R$}
                            node[below]  {}}
                            child {node[end, label=right:
                            {R2}] {}
                            edge from parent
                            node[above] {$R$}
                            node[below]  {}}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {$1-D$}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
                child {
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {D1}] {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {$D$}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
                edge from parent 
                node[above] {}
                node[below]  {$1-u$}
        }
        child {
            node{U1}        
                child{
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {$T$}] {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
            edge from parent         
                node[above] {$u$}
                node[below]  {}
        };
    \matrix[% table as tikz matrix
        matrix of nodes,
        anchor=m-4-1.west,
        xshift=1cm,
        nodes={inner xsep=\tabcolsep,minimum height=0.5*\sibdist},
      ](m)at(n-1-1-1){%
        c&b&a&c&bd&a\\
        a&c&b&a&a&c\\
        x&g&f&c&d&b\\[.5*\sibdist]
        ta&g&a&x&p&d\\
    };
    % lines around the columns:
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}\node[draw,fit=(m-1-\i) (m-2-\i) (m-3-\i) (m-4-\i),inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth](c\i){};
    % lines between the rows:
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}\draw([yshift=-.25*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c1.west)--([yshift=-.25*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c6.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or maybe better

[image]

Code:

```
\newcommand\sibdist{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=right, sloped,
    bag/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
    end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny},
    sibling distance=\sibdist,
    level 1/.style={level distance=2.0cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=3.0cm},
    every node/.style={font=\strut},
    ]
  \node(n){}
      child {
          node{U2}        
              child {
                  node[label=right:
                      ]{D2} {}
                          child {node[end, label=right:
                          {R1}] {}
                          edge from parent
                          node[above] {$1-R$}
                          node[below]  {}}
                          child {node[end, label=right:
                          {R2}] {}
                          edge from parent
                          node[above] {$R$}
                          node[below]  {}}
                          child[missing]
                  edge from parent
                  node[above] {$1-D$}
                  node[below]  {}
              }
              child {
                  node[end, label=right:
                      {D1}] {}
                  edge from parent
                  node[above] {$D$}
                  node[below]  {}
              }
              child[missing]
              edge from parent 
              node[above] {}
              node[below]  {$1-u$}
      }
      child {
          node{U1}        
              child{
                  node[end, label=right:
                      {$T$}](e) {}
                  edge from parent
                  node[above] {}
                  node[below]  {}
              }
          edge from parent         
              node[above] {$u$}
              node[below]  {}
      };
  \matrix[
      matrix of nodes,
      anchor=m-4-1.west,
      xshift=1cm,
      nodes={inner xsep=\tabcolsep,minimum height=\sibdist}
    ](m)at(n-1-1-1){%
      c&b&a&c&bd&a\\
      a&c&b&a&a&c\\
      x&g&f&c&d&b\\%[1cm]
      ta&g&a&x&p&d\\
  };
  \foreach \i in {1,...,6}\node[draw,fit=(m-1-\i) (m-2-\i) (m-3-\i) (m-4-\i),inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth](c\i){};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,3}\draw([yshift=-.5*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c1.west)--([yshift=-.5*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c6.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If the first and the second branches should be algined with the third and fourth you can insert empty childs on level 2:

```
\newcommand\sibdist{1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=right, sloped,
    bag/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
    end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt,font=\tiny},
    sibling distance=\sibdist,
    level 1/.style={level distance=2.0cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=3.0cm},
    every node/.style={font=\strut},
    ]
  \node(n){}
      child {
          node{U2}        
              child {
                  node[label=right:
                      ]{D2} {}
                          child {node[end, label=right:
                          {R1}] {}
                          edge from parent
                          node[above] {$1-R$}
                          node[below]  {}}
                          child {node[end, label=right:
                          {R2}] {}
                          edge from parent
                          node[above] {$R$}
                          node[below]  {}}
                          child[missing]
                  edge from parent
                  node[above] {$1-D$}
                  node[below]  {}
              }
              child {%empty child on level 2
                child{
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {D1}] {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {$D$}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
              }
              child[missing]
              edge from parent 
              node[above] {}
              node[below]  {$1-u$}
      }
      child {
          node{U1}        
              child{% empty child on level 2
                child{
                    node[end, label=right:
                        {$T$}](e) {}
                    edge from parent
                    node[above] {}
                    node[below]  {}
                }
              }
          edge from parent         
              node[above] {$u$}
              node[below]  {}
      };
  \matrix[
      matrix of nodes,
      anchor=m-4-1.west,
      xshift=1cm,
      nodes={inner xsep=\tabcolsep,minimum height=\sibdist}
    ](m)at(n-1-1-1){%
      c&b&a&c&bd&a\\
      a&c&b&a&a&c\\
      x&g&f&c&d&b\\%[1cm]
      ta&g&a&x&p&d\\
  };
  \foreach \i in {1,...,6}\node[draw,fit=(m-1-\i) (m-2-\i) (m-3-\i) (m-4-\i),inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth](c\i){};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,3}\draw([yshift=-.5*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c1.west)--([yshift=-.5*\sibdist]m-\i-1.center-|c6.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I am looking for. But is there any possibility to make the first and the second branch longer so that they have all the same length?

Comment: I have changed my answer. There is now an example with a longer first and second branch.

Comment: Now it is exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately I do not really understand what you did in your code. But I will try to understand it. The problem I have now is, that I copied your code it into my document and it does not work. Do I need an additional package? You can see all my involved packages above. Thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at my first example. It is a MWE. There you can see that I load the `matrix` and the `fit` libraries additionally to the `tree` library.