# how to draw this picture using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

[image]

how this diagram could be draw in latex.

Comment: I think you will need a TikZ tree package such as http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf.

Comment: @ MWijnand- yes but how, the genetic algorithm[13] name could be add in the tree structure

Comment: I don't know, but I assume it should be possible in the same way as you can put text beneath a node in a regular TikZ picture.
Maybe you can find more information in some examples such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192385/tikz-tree-beside-table and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63612/tikz-tree-drawing-with-comments-to-each-level.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: If you use **forest**, you can just use the `label` key and create a label as you would in regular TikZ.

Answer (score 6):

For starting point probably can serve the following MWE (based on answer in [Code for make WBS Structure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281097/code-for-make-wbs-structure/281104#281104)):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,trees}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners=3pt, semithick, anchor=north},
edge from parent fork down,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, thick},
         level 1/.style = {sibling distance=55mm,level distance = 22mm},
         level 2/.style = {sibling distance=44mm,level distance = 12mm},
         level 3/.style = {sibling distance=44mm,level distance = 18mm},
                        ]
    % Parents
\node   {root}
    child{node (A) {AAA}
        child {node (A1)  {A1 A1 A1}
          child {node (C1)  {C1 C1 C1 C1 C1}}
          child {node (C2)  {C2 C2 C2 C2 C2}}
            }
        child {node (A2) {A2 A2 A2 A2}}
        child {node (A3){A3 A3 A3 A3}}
          }
    child {node (B) {BBB}};
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0mm,
                  every node/.append style={draw=none, sharp corners, align=left}]
\node[below right=of B.south west] {Genetic\\ Genetic};
\node[below right=of A2.south west] {Mobility\\ Mobility\\ Mobility};
\node[below right=of A3.south west] {Critical\\ Critical\\ Critical};
\node[below right=of C1.south west] {Modified\\ Modified};
\node[below right=of C2.south west] {Dynamic\\ Dynamic\\ Dynamic\\ Dynamic\\ Dynamic};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Right text and fine tuning I left to do to you.